# How to embed a .yaml.erb into another .yaml.erb while keeping indentation?

Tags: ruby, yaml, erb

Suppose I have two files, *parent.yaml.erb* and and *child.yaml.erb* and I would like to include the contents of *child.yaml.erb* inside of *parent.yaml.erb* and calculate it in context of *parent.yaml.erb*. Example:

*parent.yaml.erb*:

```
name: parent
first:
  second:
    third: something
    <%= ERB.new(File.read('child.yaml.erb')).result(binding) %>
```

*child.yaml.erb*:

```
<% if some_condition %>
a:
  b:
    c: <%= 2+2 %>
<% end %>
```

I expect this result:

*expected_result.yaml*:

```
name: parent
first:
  second:
    third: something
    a:
      b:
        c: 4
```

What I get instead is:

*result.yaml*:

```
name: parent
first:
  second:
    third: something
    *[whitespace ends here]*
a:

  b:

    c: 4
```

Using trim_mode option from [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.5/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new) doesn't help.

How do I achieve expected result with correct indentation?

`ruby 2.6.4p104 (2019-08-28 revision 67798) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: I wonder why you want to do that in YAML with ERB and not by reading the YAML into Ruby and dumping the whole file again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way.

#### parent.yaml.erb

```erb
name: parent
first:
  second:
    third: something
<%- content = ERB.new(File.read("child.yaml.erb"), nil, "-").result().gsub(/^/,"    ") -%> 
<%= content -%>
```

#### child.yaml.erb

```erb
<% if some_condition -%>
a:
  b:
    c: <%= 2+2 %>
<% end -%>
```

#### Some explanation

- I had to enable trim mode by passing `nil` and `"-"` as 2nd and 3rd arguments to `ERB.new()`.
- With trim mode enabled, I can trim unwanted white space using `<$-` and `-%>`.
- I used `gsub` to indent by 4 spaces.

Of course, as noted in comments, it could be better to read the YAML data into memory as a hash, although I do realise you lose a lot of control of the output that way.